# PHP code to Eventbrite API returning error status_code":404

Tags: php, wordpress, api, eventbrite

I am trying to get all events of an organization by token and organisation ID but I am getting

{"status_code":404,"error_description":"The path you requested does not exist.","error":"NOT_FOUND"}

Here is my PHP code, any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$token = 'XYZ123456XYZ';
$url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/123456789/events=' . $token;

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the cURL request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Print the raw response to the console
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Parse the JSON response
$events = json_decode($response, true);

// Check for errors
if (isset($events['error'])) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $events['error_description'];
} else {
    // Loop through the events and display their information
    foreach ($events['events'] as $event) {
        echo '<h2>' . $event['name']['text'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['description']['text'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['start']['local'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['end']['local'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['venue']['name'] . '</p>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the end point URL values , tried with and without organisation IDS but nothing seems to be work. It should show all event name, description , start time etc.

Comment: A `=` in the _path_ component of the URL is highly unlikely, sure that this is not something that would belong into the query string instead?

Comment: `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/123456789/events=XYZ123456XYZ` gives a 404, `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/123456789/?events=XYZ123456XYZ` (notice the question mark?) gives a 401 Unauthorized. I'd suggest going through the [documentation](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/events) a bit more

Comment: changed the url to $url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/343775793637/?expand=venue&token=' . $token;
and the error turned from 404 to 403  "{"status_code":403,"error_description":"The feature that you requested is not available to you.","error":"NOT_AUTHORIZED"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation some more and found that the link I was using was deprecated, I am leaving the answer here for others to find it easily.

this is the link to get private token

https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/authentication#get-a-private-token

https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api-keys

```
<?
 //error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$token = 'enterurtokenhere';
$url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/{enteruridhere}/events/?status=live';

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
));

// Execute the cURL request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Print the raw response to the console
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Parse the JSON response
$events = json_decode($response, true);

// Check for errors
if (isset($events['error'])) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $events['error_description'];
} else {
    // Loop through the events and display their information
    foreach ($events['events'] as $event) {
        echo '<h2>' . $event['name']['text'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['description']['text'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['start']['local'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['end']['local'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $event['venue']['name'] . '</p>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
?>
```